# How to traverse all the cells in a 3D CGAL mesh by using BFS?

Tags: cgal

I have created the 3D mesh. I just wonder whether I can search for the adjacent cells for one special cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a Cell_handle, you can access its neighbors cells using the [`neighbor`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/TDS_3/classTriangulationDataStructure__3_1_1Cell.html#adefca3af0678944b06c5ee4a38db33bf) function:

```
Cell_handle n = cell->neighbor(i); //  0<= i < 4
```

If you want to restrict to cells in the complex, you can use the function [`is_in_complex(Cell_handle c)`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/classMeshComplex__3InTriangulation__3.html#a7b58574d2c8adfd81fa3b4f6eab1bbb5).